# Validate XML with XSD in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, dom, xsd-validation

I want to validate an xml file.  I don't know how to properly refer to the xsd.  It says "object required" for the "Set xmlDoc.schemas = strXSDFile" line.

```
Function CheckXML()

Dim strFileName As String
Dim strXSDFile As String


    strFileName = "C:\mylocation\xmlfile.txt"

    strXSDFile = "C:\mylocation\xsdfile.xsd"


    Set xmlDoc = LoadXmlFile(strFileName)
    Set xmlDoc.schemas = strXSDFile
    Set objErr = xmlDoc.validate()


    If objErr.errorCode = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No errors found"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Error parser: " & objErr.errorCode & "; " & objErr.reason
    End If

End Function

Function LoadXmlFile(Path As String) As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set LoadXmlFile = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With LoadXmlFile
        .async = False
        .validateOnParse = False
        .resolveExternals = False
        .Load Path
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: objErr is undefined in your code, what type does it have?

Answer (score 2):

Before you load the XML doc, add the schema.  You can combine the two into one function as below.  I used message boxes so I could format the text, but you could raise the issues as VBA errors instead.

```
Public Function LoadAndValidateXML(strXMLPath As String, strXSDPath As String) As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmldom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xmldom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Dim xmlschema As MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache60
    Set xmlschema = New MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache60
    xmlschema.Add "", strXSDPath

    Set xmldom.schemas = xmlschema
    xmldom.async = False
    xmldom.Load strXMLPath

    If xmldom.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Validation Error: " & xmldom.parseError.errorCode & " " & TrimWhiteSpace(xmldom.parseError.reason)
        MsgBox xmldom.parseError.srcText
    Else
        Set LoadAndValidateXML = xmldom
    End If
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function TrimWhiteSpace(strString As String) As String
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer

    For a = 1 To Len(strString)
        Select Case Mid(strString, a, 1)
            Case vbCr, vbLf, vbTab, " ":
                a = a + 1
            Case Else:
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next

    For b = Len(strString) To 1 Step -1
        Select Case Mid(strString, a, 1)
            Case vbCr, vbLf, vbTab, " ":
                b = b + 1
            Case Else:
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next

    TrimWhiteSpace = Mid(strString, a, b - a)
End Function
```

Comment: This line fails: "xmlschema.Add "", strXSDPath" ...  it says xsdfile.xsd#/schema/targetNamespace[1] The namespace '' provided differs from the schema's targetNamespace 'urn:swift:xsd:xsdfile

Comment: Also TrimWhiteSpace is not defined so I just changed it to Trim

Comment: Sorry about that - TrimWhiteSpace gets rid of leading or trailing carriage returns, newlines, tabs or spaces.  The built-in VBA Trim only removes spaces.  I added that function because there were some annoying end of line chars in the parseError strings that threw off the formatting.

Comment: For an example of how to associate the schema with the correct namespace, see  the msdn reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766451(v=vs.85).aspx). If the namespace will be changing a lot, you can add strNamespace as a third parameter to the function.  Otherwise you can hardcode it.